# Changing the selected Tab in a Tab Control using SelectedTab binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, tabs, controls

I have a View and two View Models.  I want to be able to change the displayed tab by changing the SelectedTab variable in the first ViewModel that the TabControl uses as a DataContext by changing the variable in a separate ViewModel that the SelectedTab value is bound to.

Is it failing because I have done something wrong with the OnPropertyChanged command?

The Views tab control XAML

```
 <controls:MetroAnimatedSingleRowTabControl Grid.Row="1" Name="MainTabControl" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedTab}" >
```

The first View Model that contains the SelectedTab binding for the Tab Control.

```
    private String _selectedTab = "0";

    public String SelectedTab
    {
        get { return _selectedTab; }
        set
        {
            _selectedTab = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedTab"); 
        }
    }
```

Code snippet from the second View Model to change the SelectedTab variable.

```
        var tab = new MainViewModel();
        tab.SelectedTab = "1";
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried converting your property to an int rather than a string data type.